# Extract words in between the separator

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have input like below

[image]

I want like below

[image]

I was trying with

```
Sales External?HR?Purchase Department
```

I did LISTAGG because finally i want in separate columns

Query Output would be like below,
meaning it should search for first occurrence of the separator (in this case "?", it can be anything but not common ones like "-" or "/" as the separator needs to be separate than sting value) and then extract the phrase before the first separator and create one column and put the value. Then it should look for second occurrence of the separator and then extract the word and keep creating columns, there can be multiple separators.

I tried with SPLIT_PART but it does not maintain the sequence in real data scenario and data does not come correct as per sequence.

I also tried with REGEXP_INSTR, but unable to use special characters as separators.
Any thought?

[image]

Comment: What if there are more than 3 items? Is this going to dynamically create as many columns as you need? What if there are more rows with varying number of words?

Comment: Actually, the real data is in multiple lines, but i used LISTAGG to have it in one row like above, but finally there has to be multiple columns based on these separators. I could not use Pivot thinking it would not give in the format i want, hence, doing this way. Yes, now it is only 3 columns, but it will increase in future to maximum 10 say.

Comment: Don't listagg this together if your intention is to not have it together. That's crazy bananas. Maybe consider json aggregation  or something more manageable. But I still question the varying number of columns per row. Can you include more sample data?

Comment: ok then for example i have like below                                                                            SELECT 'Sales External'
union all
SELECT 'HR'
union all
SELECT 'Purchase Department'

Comment: You can use special characters in REGEXP functions.  Use hex encoding if you have difficulties with them being printable.

Comment: @JimDemitriou : Example?

Comment: @JNevill : Provided sample data in question

Comment: Here’s a reference site for using hex codes in REGEX for ASCII characters - but I’ve provided an answer below that may work for you as well:  https://regexland.com/ascii/

Answer (score 0):

[Regex Extract](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr_all.html) should work for you:

```sql
SELECT 
  REGEXP_SUBSTR_ALL("Sales External?HR?Purchase Department", "(.*)\?")
```

You can use [LATERAL FLATTEN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html) to convert your array into rows:

```sql
WITH MY_CTE AS (
  SELECT 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR_ALL("Sales External?HR?Purchase Department", "(.*)\?")
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => MY_CTE, MODE=> 'ARRAY')
```

Deeper dive into some more cases: https://dwgeek.com/snowflake-convert-array-to-rows-methods-and-examples.html/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified version of the data. It uses a CTE with array_agg to group the rows. It then changes from arrays to columns. To add more columns, you can use max(), min(), or any_value() functions to get them through the aggregation. (Note that use of any_value() will not allow use of cached results from the result set cache since it's flagged as nondeterministic.)

```
create or replace table T1 (EMPID int, ROLE string, ACCESS string, ACCESS_LVL string, ITERATION string);

insert into T1(EMPID, ROLE, ACCESS, ACCESS_LVL, ITERATION) values
(1234, 'Sales Rep', 'Specific', 'REGION', 'DEV'),
(1234, 'Purchase Rep', 'Specific', 'EVERY', 'PROD'),
(1234, 'HR', NULL, 'Dept', 'PROD'),
(4321, 'HR', 'Foo', 'Foo', 'Foo')
;

with X as
(
    select   EMPID
            ,array_agg(nvl(ROLE,''))       within group (order by ROLE) ARR_ROLE
            ,array_agg(nvl(ACCESS,''))     within group (order by ROLE) ARR_ACCESS
            ,array_agg(nvl(ACCESS_LVL,'')) within group (order by ROLE) ARR_ACCESS_LVL
            ,array_agg(nvl(ITERATION,''))  within group (order by ROLE) ARR_ITERATION
    from T1
    group by EMPID
)
select  EMPID
       ,ARR_ROLE[0]::string       as ROLE1
       ,ARR_ROLE[1]::string       as ROLE2
       ,ARR_ROLE[2]::string       as ROLE3
       ,ARR_ACCESS[0]::string     as ACCESS1
       ,ARR_ACCESS[1]::string     as ACCESS2
       ,ARR_ACCESS[2]::string     as ACCESS3
       ,ARR_ACCESS_LVL[0]::string as ACCESS_LVL1
       ,ARR_ACCESS_LVL[1]::string as ACCESS_LVL2
       ,ARR_ACCESS_LVL[2]::string as ACCESS_LVL3
       ,ARR_ITERATION[0]::string  as ITERATION1
       ,ARR_ITERATION[1]::string  as ITERATION2
       ,ARR_ITERATION[2]::string  as ITERATION3
from X
;
```

There's nothing particular that seems interesting to sort the rows into the array so that ROLE1, ROLE2, ROLE3, etc. are deterministic. I showed simply sorting on the name of the role, but it could be any order by within that group.

Comment: Yes, the main issue i am facing is the ordering. I have created a ROW_NUMBER in real dataset and doing like this , will it work ? : array_agg(nvl(T0."ROLE",''))within group (ORDER BY T0."ROWNUMBER" asc) AS "ARRAY_ROLES",

Comment: Yes, if you change all four order by clauses that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stored proc that will produce a table result with a dynamic set of columns based on the input string and specified delimiter.

If you are looking for a way to generate dynamic column names based on values, I recommend visiting Felipe Hoffa's blog entry here:
https://medium.com/snowflake/dynamic-pivots-in-sql-with-snowflake-c763933987c

```
create or replace procedure pivot_dyn_results(input string, delimiter string) 
returns table ()
language SQL 
AS
declare

max_count integer default 0;
lcount integer default 0;
rs resultset;
stmt1 string;
stmt2 string;

begin

-- Get number of delimiter separated values (assumes no leading or trailing delimiter)
select regexp_count(:input, '\\'||:delimiter, 1) into :max_count from dual;

-- Generate the initial row-based result set of parsed values
stmt1 := 'SELECT * from lateral split_to_table(?,?)';

-- Build dynamic query to produce the pivoted column based results
stmt2 := 'select * from (select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id(-1)))) pivot(max(value) for index in (';

-- initialize look counter for resulting columns
lcount := 1;
stmt2 := stmt2 || '\'' || lcount || '\'';

-- append pivot statement for each column to be represented
FOR l in 1 to max_count do
lcount := lcount + 1;
stmt2 := stmt2 || ',\'' || lcount || '\'';
END FOR;

-- close out the pivot statement
stmt2 := stmt2 || '))';

-- execute the 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :stmt1 using (input, delimiter);
rs := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :stmt2);

return table(rs);
end;
```

Invocation:
call pivot_dyn_results([string],[delimiter]);

```
call pivot_dyn_results('Sales External?HR?Billing?Purchase Department','?');
```

Results:

[image: SEQ '1' '2' '3' '4' 1 Sales External HR Billing Purchase Department]